# windows authentication with python and SciTE

Tags: python, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-16.04, scite

I'm trying to run my selenium scripts via Jenkins on Ubunt server 16.04 without GUI.

And before to open a web page it requires make an windows authentication. I created for Windows with AutoIT and it works good but now I have to execute via Jenkins on Ubunt server, and got the following error:

```
Using deprecated data structure for setting timeouts
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/GlobalStagingERP/global.staging.erp/authentification/WindowsAuthenticationFireFoxCodeExample.exe": error=13, Permission denied
```

And I decided to do it with python and SciTE.

Also I tried 'https://username:password@my_url/' but it didn't work and got a fatal error.

This is an example how I'm using AutoIT script to handle authentication in window:

```
WinWaitActive("Authentication Required","")
MouseClick("left",331, 288,1)
Send("username")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("password")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

But how can I do it the same action in SciTE using python?

Comment: I will try this workaround:

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/uH6hzGSN1